# How to access members of an array?

Tags: arrays, sh

I have a shell script that takes command line arguments using `getopt`.  That part of my script is fine, however, I need a special case where one can submit one particular argument multiple times.

Here is the jist of how I'm handling it:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0

# once in the case statement I do the following:
while true
do
   case "$1" in

   -p) 
      paramList[$i]=$2
      ((i++))
      shift 2
      ;;
done
```

This is populating the `paramList` array properly (I think), but whenever I try the following:

```
for param in $paramList
do
   echo "Params: $param"
done
```

It only returns the very first param.  So if I do `./myscript -p blah -p blah2 -p blah3` it just returns `blah`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `case` statement you can simply add to the array like this:

```
-p) 
   paramList+=( "$2" )
   shift 2
   ;;
```

No index necessary.

To iterate over the array:

```
for param in "${paramList[@]}"
do
   echo "Params: $param"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array simply by doing this:

```
paramList=( "$@" )
```

Then you can iterate over them by doing:

```
for param in "${paramList[@]}"
do
   echo "Params: $param"
done
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is giving me too much information.  I just want the argument following the switch.  Ill put the entire loop.